# Discrete counterpart of Leibniz's rule for differentiation to minimize this function?

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

I want to find a minimum of $$\sum_{i=0}^{\eta(d)}P_i(d)$$ with respect to $d$, when summation is a convex function of $d$. If it will be just $P(d)$ then I can differentiate it. How should I proceed now?